# One page checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can i show the cart and checkout in the same page and skip "view cart" (as in the images below), I know there are plugins to do this but none of them work for me, I think my theme doesn't support such plugins, so i found a tutorial > "https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-cart-checkout-same-page" but not sure what pages to modify, I've never modified woocommerce before, any help would be appreciated. Preferred second image but either would do
https://ibb.co/knngXf (Image 1), https://ibb.co/eNwx50 (image 2)
Thanks